# Bad HTML5 Canvas rendering performance

Tags: kik

I experience very bad canvas rendering performance inside Kik for my HTML5 game in contrast to native (default) Android browser on Samsung S5 and S4 devices (models for US market).

S5 default browser gives **115 rendering operations per second**,
Kik browser gives **6-7 the same rendering operations per second**.

S5 user agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SAMSUNG SM-G900H Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.6 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36

Kik user agent: agent = Kik/7.3.0.107 (Android 4.4.2) Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-G900H Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36

Could you please provides some hints or tips what is the problem here?
I can provide the source code of my simple test (just do ctx.drawImage of the same image many times, times are measured by Benchmark.js)

Thank you,
Sergey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 4.4 shipped with an issue with the WebView that caused degraded canvas performance. Google has fixed this issue in their latest beta release (Android L) so we will simply have to wait for that. Note that this issue does not exist on versions of Android prior to 4.4